# Is there a gender neutral plural form for "salsa dancer"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, plurales, neutralidad-de-género

I ask specifically for:

> Salseros y Salseras

*(male and female Salsa dancers, respectively)*

It would be great to be able to address a mixed group of people with a single unifying word.

Comment: Neuter plural in Spanish is the same as masculine plural. It does not mean you are overlooking women or assimilating them into the male group. Nowadays a few forget this _neutrality_ and try to forcefully correct it, but the norm remains and consensus overwhelmingly supports it. Instead, you have to disambiguate if you need to say they're only _men_: _salseros/bailarines_ varones (or hombres.) Using both genders in plural in Spanish is a form of overcorrection, and thus a mistake, just like regularizing an irregular verb.

Comment: If you don't want to use *salseros* or *salser@s*, you could say *aficionados de la salsa* (for a poster or announcement written in Spanish) or *salsa aficionados* (for a poster or announcement written in English).  Technically it faces the same problem as *salseros* but I think since it is such a clear cognate with English, it would be a good work-around.

Answer (score 13):

Spanish is not a great language when it comes to gender-neutral forms.

Technically, **"salseros" is the *grammatically* gender-neutral plural form for both "salsero" and "salsera"**. However, being that it ends in -o, it is more identified with the male form and thus it is not seen as *socially* gender-neutral.

If you wanted to use a different word for whatever reason, you could use "**bailarines de salsa**" instead, which literally means "salsa dancers".

> **[bailarín, na](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=bailar%C3%ADn)**
>   1. adj. Que baila. Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.
>   2. m. y f. Persona que ejercita o profesa el arte de bailar.

"Bailarines" can work better than "salseros" because it ends with an -e (seen by some as more neutral than the -o in "salseros").
This only works in plural, though, since the singular forms would still be male "bailarín" and female "bailarina".

Also, as mentioned by Gustavson, *[salsero](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=salsero)* has at least four additional meanings not related to salsa music, so maybe *bailarines* can be more clear too.

Comment: The plurals would be *bailarines* and *bailarinas*, so the thing doesn't work in plural either...

Comment: "bailarines de salsa" sounds perfect to me. "salsero/salsera", in countries where *salsa* is not so popular, will tend to be interpreted like this: *Recipiente en el que se lleva la salsa para servirla* (sauce or gravy boat) :)

Comment: @walen Not at all. Please do.

Comment: Although it's true that "salseros" could be misinterpreted, "bailarines de salsa" is not seen as more neutral, at least in Spain. Everyone who considers salseros to be male only would also consider bailarines de salsa to be male only too.

Answer (score 10):

Spanish does have a gender-neutral form for that, "salseros". Saying "salseros y salseras" should be avoided. ([source](http://www.rae.es/consultas/los-ciudadanos-y-las-ciudadanas-los-ninos-y-las-ninas)).

> La mención explícita del femenino solo se justifica cuando la oposición de sexos es relevante en el contexto: El desarrollo evolutivo es similar en los niños y las niñas de esa edad. La actual tendencia al desdoblamiento indiscriminado del sustantivo en su forma masculina y femenina va contra el principio de economía del lenguaje y se funda en razones extralingüísticas. Por tanto, deben evitarse estas repeticiones, que generan dificultades sintácticas y de concordancia, y complican innecesariamente la redacción y lectura de los textos.

It is unfortunate that there is no distinction between the male plural form and the gender-neutral plural form, but that is just the way Spanish is.

Comment: This is an ongoing debate in Spanish: is the plural ending in _-os_ representative of both genders? Gramatically it is but more and more people are starting to say [_vascos y vascas_](https://elpais.com/diario/2008/04/10/sociedad/1207778401_850215.html). By the way, welcome to [spanish.se]! We hope to see you around :)

Comment: @Hawkings: The issue is that most people here don't speak Spanish well enough to make that distinction. If they see only salseros, they might be under the impression that female dancers are being left out.

Comment: @Spikee maybe the norm would change with time, as language tends to regularize. But it is currently part of the basics, so a good Spanish class should teach this early on :)

Comment: @Spikee, when you say "*if they see*" do you mean that the question is specific to written language rather than spoken language?

Comment: @Rafael I'm a Spanish (language and culture) enthusiast, I'm all for Spanish classes :).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was asking with written (digital) text in mind, but both.

Answer (score 3):

In informal written Spanish, it has become common to use *-@s* as an ending meaning "*-os* or *-as*". So *salser@s* would be understood to be an intentionally gender-inclusive plural of *salsero/-a*.

Pronouncing that is another matter.

Comment: Note that this usage is discouraged, incorrect, and inconvenient: http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/arroba/

Comment: @Miguel, *discouraged* is a valid criticism, although it needs qualification (anything can be described as *discouraged* if you can find one person who discourages it), and although *inconvenient* isn't quite the right English word I understand what you mean. But *incorrect* is a category error: orthographic usage can be standard or non-standard, but it cannot be correct or incorrect. The fact that it is non-standard is flagged by the answer specifying "*informal written Spanish*".

Comment: Where I live this is common.  I personally don't like it myself, but it certainly solves OP's problem.  +1.

Comment: @walen, that was how the function of the RAE was conceived 300 years ago, but modern linguists have a very different understanding of their job. To [quote](https://elpais.com/diario/2008/06/15/galicia/1213525095_850215.html) the current director of the RAE, "*lo que la Real Academia tiene claro es que no crea idioma, apenas da unidad al que origina la sociedad.*" If you want a specific example of how they document rather than dictate, see [iros](https://elpais.com/cultura/2017/07/17/actualidad/1500312948_438834.html).

Comment: @Peter Taylor It is discouraged by Fundeu, a recognized source for Spanish in journalism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fund%C3%A9u_BBVA

Comment: @walen, I contend that the change was to make the *rules* correct rather than the word, because rules of language are like laws of science: an attempt to summarise and explain based on observation which need to be updated as new observations are made.